# Realizar salto de Línea con Canvas

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, canvas

les agradezco su ayuda, estoy haciendo un proyecto que toma los datos de una base de datos SQLite y los imprime en un PDF por medio de canvas, sin embargo cuando una línea es muy larga, esta se corta. Necesito realizar un salto de línea, sin embargo no se como hacerlo, he intentado por medio de staticlayout, pero sigue sin funcionar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La mala noticia es que esto no funciona en canvas. Sin embargo puedes utilizar el método `measureText()` para medir el texto.

En el siguiente ejemplo voy a escribir una función para insertar saltos de línea.
Por favor lea los comentarios dentro del código:

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let padding = 30;
let w = canvas.width - 2*padding;   
//el texto a utilizar
let texto = "El veloz murci\351lago hind\372 com\355a feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cig\374e\361a tocaba el saxof\363n detr\341s del palenque de paja.";
//las coordenadas x e y del punto donde empieza cada línea
let x = padding;
let y = 50;

let alturaDeLinea = 25;

ctx.font = "12px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "#333";

// llama la función ajusteDeTexto
ajusteDeTexto(texto, x, y, w, alturaDeLinea);
            


function ajusteDeTexto(texto, x, y, maxWidth, alturaDeLinea){
        // crea el array de las palabras del texto
        let palabrasRy = texto.split(" ");
        // inicia la variable var lineaDeTexto
        let lineaDeTexto = "";
        // un bucle for recorre todas las palabras
                for(let i = 0; i < palabrasRy.length; i++) {
                let testTexto = lineaDeTexto + palabrasRy[i] + " ";
                // calcula la anchura del texto textWidth 
                let textWidth = ctx.measureText(testTexto).width;
                // si textWidth > maxWidth
                        if (textWidth > maxWidth  && i > 0) {
                        // escribe en el canvas la lineaDeTexto
                        ctx.fillText(lineaDeTexto, x, y);
                        // inicia otra lineaDeTexto         
                        lineaDeTexto = palabrasRy[i]+ " " ;
                        // incrementa el valor de la variable y 
                        //donde empieza la nueva lineaDeTexto
                        y += alturaDeLinea;
                        }else {// de lo contrario,  si textWidth <= maxWidth 
                        lineaDeTexto = testTexto;
                        }
                }// acaba el bucle for
        // escribe en el canvas la última lineaDeTexto
        ctx.fillText(lineaDeTexto, x, y);
}
```

```css
canvas{border:solid}
```

```html
<canvas width="250" height="165" id="canvas">Su navegador no soporta canvas :( </canvas>
```